# Function or Table for normalizing accented vowels (and other symbols) in a string

Tags: javascript, string, ascii, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

Many languages have letters that only differ from each other by an accent or another sign, especially vowels.

If one wants to replace those vowels so that the ones with a sign are replaced with the corresponding base character there is the need of a table to easily perform the replacement.

I would like to know

1) if this table is available, in a thorough form for most languages.

Or

2) if programming languages have a string utility function to perform the same operation (I need it in Javascript, especially for vowels).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not have any built-in utilities for that operation, and it's not usual to see this kind of behaviour in most modern programming languages (the only programming language that I've found with this feature is Ruby, with regular expressions).

You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/3255098).